# Scaling/Translating a Shape to a given Rectangle using AffineTransform

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, shapes, affinetransform

I'm trying to scale/translate a java.awt.**Shape** with **AffineTransform** in order to draw it in a defined bounding Rectangle.

Moreover, I want to paint it in a drawing Area having a '**zoom**' parameter.

I tried various concatenations of AffineTransform but I couldn't find the correct sequence. For example, the following solution was wrong:

```
double zoom=(...);/* current zoom */
Rectangle2D viewRect=(...)/** the rectangle where we want to paint the shape */
Shape shape=(...)/* the original shape that should fit in the rectangle viewRect */
Rectangle2D bounds=shape.getBounds2D();

double ratioW=(viewRect.getWidth()/bounds.getWidth());
double ratioH=(viewRect.getHeight()/bounds.getHeight());


AffineTransform transforms[]=
    {
    AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoom, zoom),
    AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-bounds.getX(),-bounds.getY()),
    AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(viewRect.getX(),viewRect.getY()),
    AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(ratioW, ratioH)
    };


AffineTransform tr=new AffineTransform();
for(int i=0;i< transforms.length;++i)
    {
    tr.concatenate(transforms[i]);
    }

Shape shape2=tr.createTransformedShape(shape);
graphics2D.draw(shape2);
```

Any idea about the correct AffineTransform ?

Many thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) transformations are concatenated "in the most commonly useful way", which may be regarded as *last in*, *first-out* order. The effect can be seen in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon). Given the sequence below, the resulting `Shape` is first rotated, then scaled and finally translated.

```
at.translate(SIZE/2, SIZE/2);
at.scale(60, 60);
at.rotate(Math.PI/4);
return at.createTransformedShape(...);
```

Comment: I'll validate your answer as your expression "Last-In , First Out" inspired the solution

Comment: It's a useful notion for reasoning about the result; but, of course, there is no _queue_, only a single transform that subsumes the series of operations.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by trashgod's answer, the correct sequence was:

```
AffineTransform transforms[]=
{
AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoom, zoom),
AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(viewRect.getX(),viewRect.getY()),
AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(ratioW, ratioH),
AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-bounds.getX(),-bounds.getY())
};



AffineTransform tr=new AffineTransform();
for(int i=0;i< transforms.length;++i)
 {
 tr.concatenate(transforms[i]);
 }
```

Comment: +1 It might be worth adding the original code for a _before_ and _after_ comparison.