# Flip Image with Graphics2D

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics2d

I've been trying to figure out how to flip an image for a while, but haven't figured out yet.

I'm using `Graphics2D` to draw an `Image` with

```
g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null)
```

I just need a way to flip the image on the horizontal or vertical axis.

If you want you can have a look at the [full source on github](https://github.com/r3Fuze/2DProject/tree/master/src/com/fuze/project/).

Comment: Instead of having us look at your entire source, make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: If you google "Graphics2D rotate image" you'll find lots of tutorials

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/image/flipping-a-buffered-image:

```
// Flip the image vertically
AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1);
tx.translate(0, -image.getHeight(null));
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
image = op.filter(image, null);


// Flip the image horizontally
tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, 1);
tx.translate(-image.getWidth(null), 0);
op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
image = op.filter(image, null);

// Flip the image vertically and horizontally; equivalent to rotating the image 180 degrees
tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, -1);
tx.translate(-image.getWidth(null), -image.getHeight(null));
op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
image = op.filter(image, null);
```

Comment: +1 for `-1` :-) A related example is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513).

Comment: Works perfectly and is super simple! I use this with imageicons by simply converting them to buffered images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053214/converting-an-imageicon-to-a-bufferedimage

Answer (score 43):

The **easiest** way to flip the image is by negative scaling it.
Example:

```
g2.drawImage(image, x + width, y, -width, height, null);
```

That will flip it horizontally. This will flip it vertically:

```
g2.drawImage(image, x, y + height, width, -height, null);
```

Comment: This is almost good.
It should be like 
g2.drawImage(image, x+height, y, width, -height, null); reason for this is because negative scale will move image to left, so you have to compensate this movement.

Comment: Yeah +1 @T.G for balancing out the negativity.

Comment: I believe this is more efficient than using AffineTransform. Anyone correct me if I am wrong. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a transform on your `Graphics`, that should rotate the image just fine. Below is a sample code that you can use to acheive this:

```
AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform(); 
//rotate the image by 45 degrees 
affineTransform.rotate(Math.toRadians(45), x, y); 
g2d.drawImage(image, m_affineTransform, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the width and height of the image to make sure it's properly scaled:

```
int width = image.getWidth(); int height = image.getHeight();
```

Then, you need to draw it:

```
//Flip the image both horizontally and vertically
g2d.drawImage(image, x+(width/2), y+(height/2), -width, -height, null);
//Flip the image horizontally
g2d.drawImage(image, x+(width/2), y-(height/2), -width, height, null);
//Flip the image vertically
g2d.drawImage(image, x-(width/2), y+(height/2), width, -height, null);
```

This is how I do it, anyways.

Answer (score -1):

**Rotate Image Vertical 180 Degrees**

```
File file = new File(file_Name);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file         
AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, -1);
tx.translate(-bufferedImage.getWidth(null), -bufferedImage.getHeight(null));
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File(file_Name));
```