# Converting an ImageIcon to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, imageicon

I've been trying to convert a `ImageIcon` to `BufferedImage`... And I've had no luck.

I have a pre-existing ImageIcon that needs to be converted to a Buffered Image for the vast amount of BufferedImage operations that exist.

I have found a few ways, but all of them are hugely CPU intensive.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
    icon.getIconWidth(),
    icon.getIconHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
// paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
g.dispose();
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you very much, I had previously came accross this method, but quickly shot it down due to my immiediet assumption that it would perform badly, but after trying it your way, it all seems to work fine.

Comment: `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` if there are transparent pixels in the icon.

Comment: Shouldn't we also do `g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src)` before calling `paintIcon` to copy all the transparent pixels as is, not as strictly "transparent black"?

Answer (score 11):

See [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html), [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) and [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

```
ImageIcon yourImage;
Image image = yourImage.getImage();
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

Comment: Use this if the ImageIcon contains a BufferedImage, or Werner's answer otherwise.

Comment: That works on Windows but not on Linux (tried on Ubuntu).

Answer (score -3):

I tried something called Scalr, view the code below

`Scalr.resize((BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(file),
                    Method.SPEED, 250, OP_ANTIALIAS, OP_BRIGHTER);`

Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question. You're just reading a file, not converting an ImageIcon object to a BufferedImage object