# Convert imagicon to image

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I need to convert an ImageIcon into an Image for a program how should I go about doing it? I there a method of casting I can use or a built in method to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting an ImageIcon to a BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053214/converting-an-imageicon-to-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: Something other than http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage()?

Comment: It's not really the same thing though the bufferedimage

Comment: *"I need to convert an ImageIcon into an Image"*  This wreaks of 'bad design'.  Supposedly you originally had a reference to an image in order to create an icon, so just use the original!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer from the question I linked. I'm not sure which `Image` you mean, save it as a file or get a java `Image` instance, but you can use just the second method if you mean the latter, or use the former (which depends on the latter) if you need that.

```
// format should be "jpg", "gif", etc.
public void saveIconToFile(ImageIcon icon, String filename, String format) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage image = iconToImage(icon);
  File output = new File(filename);
  ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, format, outputfile);
}

public BufferedImage iconToImage(ImageIcon icon) {
  BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
      icon.getIconWidth(),
      icon.getIconHeight(),
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();

  // paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
  icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
  g.dispose();

  return bi;
}
```