# ActionListener doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I wanted to make a 2D game. I started making the drawing class, but I came across a problem: the `ActionListener` wouldn't work. It wouldn't draw or output my message to say it was working. Here is the code:

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int count = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, Boot.WIDTH, Boot.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Boot.WIDTH, Boot.HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("Path count: " + count, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I would assume this would work, as I used this way of drawing in other projects. What would be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to keep a reference to a Graphics object and call `paint()` directly. You're supposed to call `repaint()`, and wait for Swing to call the `paintComponent()` method, that you should override to perform your custom paintings on the Graphics object that Swing passes as argument to the method.

See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html for more information.

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int count = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, Boot.WIDTH, Boot.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Boot.WIDTH, Boot.HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("Path count: " + count, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Duncan Palmer and Boot.frame.getGraphics(), do nothing, will go away on first Swing event that internally to repaint JComponent, do nothing without saving to BufferedImage +1

Comment: Does it matter if I use a AWT Frame or Swing JFrame?

Comment: @Duncan: Yes it probably matters. This is a Swing application, and so you shouldn't be using a Frame object at all, only a JFrame. Otherwise you risk losing many of the advantages of Swing.

Comment: So you're saying that you do not see the hi message each time the JButton that uses this ActionListener is pressed?

Comment: It isn't for a JButton, this is for drawing to the JFrames JPanel .

Comment: @Duncan: then why the ActionListener? If you don't have a mechanism for calling `repaint()` then why would you expect the code to change count or repaint the GUI? -- unless you're placing the ActionListener in a Swing Timer or something similar.

Comment: I thought that is how you did it. How would I draw to the JPanel contiously?

Comment: Thought that was how you did what? It appears that there is much you need to clarify, especially exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer : Here have a look [How to Draw String on Click, of a Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809514/using-the-coordinate-plane-in-the-jframe/10811315#10811315)