# JFrame won't let me drawString();

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, drawstring

I need help because I am trying to code a game in Java.
I was stopped in my tracks when I found out that it would not draw a string to the JFrame.
I have tried several methods of getting around this and done lots of research but found nothing.
This is the code:-
Oregon (Main Class):

```
package com.lojana.oregon.client;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.lojana.oregon.src.Desktop;
import com.lojana.oregon.src.Keyboard;
import com.lojana.oregon.src.Mouse;
import com.lojana.oregon.src.Paint;

public class Oregon extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Currently unused but there will be a use for it in the future
    public Desktop desktop;

    public String TITLE = "Oregon";

    public Oregon() {
        /* Window code */
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setSize(640, 640);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        /* Extra code for Window */
        addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
        addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Paint.paint(g);
    }
}
```

GuiButton (Painting Class):

```
package com.lojana.oregon.src;

import java.awt.*;

public class GuiButton {
    public GuiButton(Graphics g, String text, Font font, int coordX, int coordY,
            int textX, int textY, int width, int height) {
        Color border = Color.gray;
        Color fill = Color.white;
        Color textColor = Color.black;

        Stroke borderSize = new BasicStroke(8);

        g.setColor(border);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(borderSize);
        g.drawRect(coordX, coordY, width, height);
        g.setColor(fill);
        g.fillRect(coordX, coordY, width, height);
        g.setColor(textColor);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(text, textX, textY);
    }
}
```

GuiMainMenu (The file that uses the GuiButton file):

```
package com.lojana.oregon.src;

import java.awt.*;

public class GuiMainMenu {
    public static void paint(Graphics g) {
        new GuiButton(g, "Start Game", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20), 60, 80, 20, 20, 240, 40);
    }
}
```

If you know how to fix it, please comment.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: What do you mean it won't draw the `String`? Are you getting an exception? Does everything except `drawString` work?

Comment: I have tried to make it draw a String to the JFrame using the paint(Graphics g) method. The text I have tried to draw will not show up. When I have tried using just the drawString() method in the main file, it shows the text but shows the program behind it.

Comment: Where the heck is the Paint class? this whole approach seems farked including your trying to draw directly on a JFrame. But also there's a lot of code that you're not showing us including critical code. I urge you to go through the Swing drawing tutorials which you can find at the main Java tutorial page to see how to draw correctly.

Comment: The main paint() method is in the Main Class (Oregon.java). I have been able to drawString() many times but that was when I was doing it with an Applet.

Comment: I was asking about the Paint class, not so much the paint() method. Also, this is not a java.awt.Applet, but a javax.swing.JFrame, and graphics are done differently. Again, please read the API.

Comment: How can I read the API? Where is it? Sorry :P

Comment: Save the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) link and refer to it frequently.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please do have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809514/using-the-coordinate-plane-in-the-jframe/10811315#10811315), as to How to draw String on JPanel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing programs are supposed to override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)` and directly to the `JFrame`. See this article for details:
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/

In addition it would be better to override the `paintComponent` of a `JPanel` that is added to the (content pane of) `JFrame` instead of the `JFrame` itself, because you want to draw into this content pane. See this tutorial for details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html