# Dynamically sizing 2D draw box in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm writing a graphic calculator via Java GUI (yes I know there's libraries for this already), when the user types in a function I.E. x^6, I want the drawbox to dynamically size itself, according to the minimum and maximum.

For example, if the user enters x^2 from -4 to 4 I have a min of 0 and a max of 16, so I'd want to display the whole graph in the box, and size it properly. Right now the graph is very small and if I use x^6 as the polynomial it looks very cramped.

Here's where I'm at.

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    double myStart1 = Double.parseDouble(myStart);
    double myEnd1 = Double.parseDouble(myEnd);
    g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    g2.scale(5.0, 5.0);
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double( -myStart1 * 100,0,  -myEnd1 * 100,0));
    if (min < 0) {
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, -min * 100, 0, -max * 100));
    } else {
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, min * 100, 0, -max * 100));
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < x.length) {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x[i], -y[i], x[i + 1], -y[i + 1]));

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Without further context, `paint` is not responsible for resizing the content, the component is.

Comment: yes, but do I use the scale property of g2 to do this? What does scale actually do? Does it actually shift the components of the drawbox or does it just make things bigger?

Comment: It's would be exactly like trying to scale an image in something like photoshop.  It's going to effect the overall pixel size...

Answer (score 2):

At least consider [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info), which scales to fill the preferred size of the enclosing `ChartPanel` and supports zooming via right-click or mouse-wheel.

Addendum: If an external library is proscribed, `SineTest`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513), may be an approach.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597045/230513 */
public class ChartPanelTest {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {

        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");
        for (double x = -4; x < 4.01; x += 0.1) {
            series.add(x, Math.pow(x, 6d));
        }
        return new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "f(x) = x^6", "x", "y", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        f.add(chartPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for school, so JFree is out of the question unfortunately.