# how to generate 2d curve in java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I have a 2d array in which rows represents the input and columns represents an output.
I want to generate a 2d curve based on this array in Java. with the input as horizontal axis and output as vertical axis.

Comment: I'd probably just find some third-party library to do it for me.

Comment: See also [tag:jfreechart] or this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out...

- [Geometric Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/primitives.html)
- [Drawing Geometric Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)
- [Quadratic and Cubic Curves](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8443)

For starters

Comment: +1 See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513)