# Rotating an Object

Tags: java, swing, rotation, awt, graphics2d

I know how to rotate the image but how would I rotate the acctual Objet? I can't use `g2d.rotate();` because I have multiple things drawn with the `paint()` method and I only wan't one of the to rotate.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note it is possible to rotate a `Graphics` for one object, then rotate it back for everything else.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: IIUC, you can save & restore the transform, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513).

Comment: @Fiskpotatis accept answers if they've helped you by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Since yours is a Swing application, you don't want to draw in the `paint(...)` method but rather in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JComponent-derived class.
- To rotate a single object consider creating a copy of your Graphics object by calling `create()` on the original, calling `rotate(...)` on the new Graphics instance, drawing the rotated item with the new Graphics2D instance, and then disposing the copied Graphics object.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform images with the java.awt.geom.AffineTransform class or implement your own rotation matrix.

Rotating an actual object implies you know its current location, orientation and pivot point. Rotation matrix is the solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix