# Drawing Graphing Grid with Java.awt

Tags: java, swing, drawing, awt

Are there any libraries for drawing an X, Y Axis/Grid for Graphing. For example, graphing inequalities, or linear equations, etc...

Or is it possible to use awt/swing? Basically what I'm looking to be able to do is draw something like this:

[image]

Comment: [`MapPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513) is an example; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that any problems you encounter using the approach shown.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a look at [Perfoming Custom Panting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: [`SineTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513) shows how to plot using cartesian coordinates.