# Reversing the JFrame Y coordinate?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-2d

I've been working on a little side scroller for fun, and I always wondered how I would "reverse" the `JFrame` Y coordinates.

Instead of the Y coordinate starting from the top, it should start from the bottom.

I made a fancy diagram to make things more clear:

[image]

This is nothing that would be useful to me at thus point in time. But it would be good to know how to do it if for some reason I would need to do it.

Comment: This could be achieved by using an `AffineTransform` on the `Graphics` instance of the custom component.  But beware that events and other such things won't be translated.

Comment: Also consider the approach outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to subtract y from frame height.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`y-=yAmount` 
or even 
`y--;` 
Let me explain, x and y start at 0, that is the top left corner, adding to x and/or y will put it lower to the right. Your image says that y should start there as 0 and to do that you can do
`int y2 = 0; int y = offsetY + y2;`
by doing that all you have to do is set y2, y and make sure that offsetY is set to your current y to make it a relative change.

Here is a few functions you could use

`public void changePositionRelative(int xChange, int yChange){
x += xChange;
y += yChange;
}`

`public void resetPosition(){
x = offsetX;
y = offsetY;
}`