# Cartesian Plane in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

After learning cycles, arrays, methods,...I started playing around with graphics but I encountered some problems. I was looking for some example when I saw this one: http://javaceda.blogspot.ch/2010/06/draw-cartesian-coordinate-system-in.html

It provides an example of a cartesian plane in Java. I can understand pretty much everything of that code ( except a few lines like invokelater, SwingUtilities and I will take a look at them later..).

Let's say that now I want to create a class "Point" with constructors, getters, a method that converts Cartesian Coordinates of a point into "Pixel Coordinates" and a method that print the point on the plane.

So, here is the code taken from the link:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Cartesian {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    CartesianFrame frame = new CartesianFrame();
    frame.showUI();
   }
  });
 }

}

class CartesianFrame extends JFrame {
 CartesianPanel panel;

 public CartesianFrame() {
  panel = new CartesianPanel();
  add(panel);
 }

 public void showUI() {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setTitle("Cartesian");
  setSize(700, 700);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}

class CartesianPanel extends JPanel {
 // x-axis coord constants
 public static final int X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD = 50;
 public static final int X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD = 600;
 public static final int X_AXIS_Y_COORD = 600;

 // y-axis coord constants
 public static final int Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD = 50;
 public static final int Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD = 600;
 public static final int Y_AXIS_X_COORD = 50;

 //arrows of axis are represented with "hipotenuse" of 
 //triangle
 // now we are define length of cathetas of that triangle
 public static final int FIRST_LENGHT = 10;
 public static final int SECOND_LENGHT = 5;

 // size of start coordinate lenght
 public static final int ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT = 6;

 // distance of coordinate strings from axis
 public static final int AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE = 20;


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  super.paintComponent(g);

  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  // x-axis
  g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD,
     X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD);
  // y-axis
  g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD,
     Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD);

  // draw origin Point
  g2.fillOval(
    X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD - (ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT / 2), 
    Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT / 2),
    ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT, ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT);

  // numerate axis
  int xCoordNumbers = 10;
  int yCoordNumbers = 10;
  int xLength = (X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD - X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD)
      / xCoordNumbers;
  int yLength = (Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD)
      / yCoordNumbers;

  // draw x-axis numbers
  for(int i = 1; i < xCoordNumbers; i++) {
   g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength),
     X_AXIS_Y_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
     X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength),
     X_AXIS_Y_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT);
   g2.drawString(Integer.toString(i), 
     X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength) - 3,
     X_AXIS_Y_COORD + AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE);
  }

  //draw y-axis numbers
  for(int i = 1; i < yCoordNumbers; i++) {
   g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
     Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength), 
     Y_AXIS_X_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT,
     Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength));
   g2.drawString(Integer.toString(i), 
     Y_AXIS_X_COORD - AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE, 
     Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength));
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the class Point that I want to add:

```
class Point{
      public int x,y;

        public Point(int x,int y){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }
        public Point FromCartToPix() {
            this.x=X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD+(x*xLength);
            this.y=Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (y * yLength);
            return this;

        }
        public int GetX(){
            return this.x;
        }
        public int GetY(){
            return this.y;
        }
        public void DrawPoint(){
            g2.fillOval(
                    this.FromCartToPix().Getx(), 
                    this.FromCartToPix().Gety(),
                    ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT, ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT);
        }
}
```

The Java Manual that I have, has just a small chapter about Java Graphics and Swing, for that reason I am not able to implement this class. I think that it should be inserted inside

```
PaintComponent(Graphics g)
```

otherwise I wouldn't be able to use

```
g2.filloval
```

but then I couldn't use

```
Point a = new Point (2,3);
```

inside the main

I know it's a bit a vague and general question but I am not able to get it to work. I searched a lot about the usage of Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g, but can't find a precise explanation, even on Javadocs.

If u know a link that explain it I would be grateful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9371961/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Point` class doesn't have access to the `Graphics2D` object of the `CartesianPanel`.

You should move the functionality of your `FromCartToPix` and `DrawPoint` methods to the `CartesionPanel`. This way you can actually draw the points and you separate the data (`Point`) from the UI (the `CartesionPanel`).

```
// add in CartesionPanel
private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

public void drawPoint(Point point) {
    points.add(point);
    repaint();
}

private void drawPointOnPanel(Point point, Graphics g) {
    final int pointDiameter = 5;
    final int x = X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (point.x * xLength) - pointDiameter / 2;
    final int y = Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (point.y * yLength) - pointDiameter / 2;
    g.fillOval(x, y, pointDiameter, pointDiameter);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // existing code ...

    // draw points
    points.forEach(p -> drawPointOnPanel(p, g))
}
```

In your `main` function you could draw `Point`s by:

```
CartesianFrame frame = new CartesianFrame();
frame.showUI();

frame.panel.drawPoint(new Point(3, 4));
```

Comment: I didn't even know that there is a .forEach in java. So it basically iterates through each point and prints them using the drawPointOnPanel method? And what about the name of the variable point (e.g. Point s) ? I would just need to do: Point s = new Point (3,4) and then frame.panel.drawPoint( s );

Comment: @Spinnaker The [`.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) method is new Java 8. You are understanding it correctly, yes.