# Java Swing Widget that models a Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to create, in native Java Swing, a GUI widget that presents a Cartesian coordinate display that permits a user to place a point on the grid, which then maps to two values available for input into the program? What i hope to do is have a single widget that takes the place of two JSliders. I am not requesting code, but rather high level design suggestions. thanks.

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959112/cartesian-plane-in-java

Comment: in the ball-park of what i'm asking. I will carefully review the code to see if i can leverage this design. Thanks.